# GPU parallelism with the ability to regularly clear buffer?

Tags: c++, opencl

I've found a way to break up a long-running algorithm into parallel chunks.  I don't quite understand if my approach to implementing this in OpenCL will do the trick.

One of the hurdles for me is that for the "results" I'm calculating I don't know how many to expect on each task execution.

So my plan is to create a buffer with enough space for 10 results, for example, and another buffer that simply stores a value indicating if the buffer was filled up.

The other problem I have is that I'm potentially launching many tasks, and I don't want to pre-calculate the inputs into one big long buffer, since that could be quite a lot of data, I just want to calculate the inputs right before firing off each task.

For example, this is some pseudo-code of an attempted approach:

```
* Create a vector to store all results
* Create the "results" buffer.
* Create the "is-filled" buffer to store whether results buffer was filled.

while (some condition) {
    // Before task.
    * Create the "input" buffer with data (input data comes from an expensive function).
    * Update kernel arguments.

    // Run task.
    queue.enqueueTask(kernel);

    // After task.
    * Read the "is-filled" buffer to determine whether "results" buffer is full.
    if ("results" buffer is full) {
       * Read the "results" buffer into the vector.
       * Read the "input" buffer (now changed to indicate next inputs to 'resume' task)
       * Reset "results" & "is-filled" buffers
    }

}

Read remaining "results" buffer into the vector.
```

This feels awkward, if there was another way to deal with buffers filling up then I'd like to know.

The most concerning thing though is that the "After task" section blocks execution and prevents parallelism from occurring.

So my issues that are a roadblock to parallelism are; variable number of results, and changing the arguments before each task.  My attempted workflow may be even more problematic :)

How would you approach this?

I have found this thread where the asker talks about regularly clearing out buffers while the workers wait.  But I can't find any elaboration about this technique.
[OpenCL read variable size result buffer from the GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903225/opencl-read-variable-size-result-buffer-from-the-gpu)

Comment: Use double buffering then. It would let all happen at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, I've got multiple buffering working.  What I'm doing is writing a buffer at the start of each loop, doing a non-blocking read into a vector of vectors at the end of the loop, and calling queue.finish() after the loop and before consuming the data (which is now split up a bit, but I can deal with that).  It means I'm sending more memory to and from the device though.  I'll probably need a second loop or wrap the whole thing in another loop to go back and resume any tasks where the buffer had filled up, though it's less likely to happen now; I should probably still handle that case.

Comment: Maybe you can use events instead of  if ("results" buffer is full)? So that part can drive the rest instead of checking at each step, if that part can be worked independently. Did you get more performance with double buffering until now?

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into how I can use events now.  Yes it looks like I'm executing concurrently with the new approach to buffering.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the idea of using events to communicate to the host that the buffer is full?

Comment: Event is for fine grained control. With it, things can respond faster than explicitly waiting for something. Using callback with an event makes host-functions triggered by device-side command completions. In your situation, each operation would increment a counter with help of event callback and after it is 9-10, that callback calls the necessary buffer clean function. So you can send 10-20 of them at a time and only after 10th, buffer gets cleared and also you can use user events to make next batch of commands wait until buffer clear action is complete.